# Is there a way to detect if a mic is used by another app in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

We're developing an web app (using ReactJS) which includes a video app in it.
We want to detect if another application or tab is using the mic, in order to prevent echo issues.
Is there a way to do it via javascript?

We're looking to have something like `isUsed()` in `MediaDeviceInfo`